# laravel return json with error instead of redirection after validation FormRequest

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request, response

I've a controller with method

```
public function foo(FooRequest $request)
    {
        return "OK"
    }
```

FooRequest extends FormRequest and has

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'id' => ['required', 'numeric', 'exists:partners,id'],
            'manager_id' => ['nullable', 'numeric'],
        ];
    }
```

If I enter invalid id it redirects me to /. How can I disable this redirect and show json exception?

json  exception is already implemented(something like JException(code, exception, errors),I just need to understand how to get rid of redirect and call to this JException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common case you need a json response instead of redirection is in API usages. So, you will need to add the following header in your call

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Otherwise, check this example on how to validate the request and handle the validation failure.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: It was pretty close. I've put Accept: aplication/json header and it works fine

Answer (score 7):

I've put `Accept: aplication/json` header and it works fine